# Match file in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6

I have a problem where I can't get a 'msg box' that tells me files that I have browsed match with files in the database. I use an SQL Server database and I have already inserted data that matches with the files that I am browsing. This is my code:

```
Private Sub CmdUp_Click()

db

End Sub

Public Sub db()

Dim DBCon As ADODB.Connection
Dim Cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strName As String
 Dim file As String

file = Text1.Text

Set DBCon = New ADODB.Connection
    DBCon.CursorLocation = adUseClient

DBCon.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=mforce; User=root;Password=;Option=3;"

Set Cmd = New ADODB.Command
Cmd.ActiveConnection = DBCon
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Sample FROM static WHERE ID = 1"

Set Rs = Cmd.Execute

Do While Not Rs.EOF

    Rs.MoveNext

Loop

 If Form1.Text1.Text = strName Then
   MsgBox " sample match"

End If
DBCon.Close

'Delete all references
Set Rs = Nothing
Set Cmd = Nothing
Set DBCon = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Where does `strName` get a value assigned?

Comment: your Do/Loop does nothing.  you probably want to test db values against whatever you are looking for.  `strName`, `file` and `Form1.Text1.Text` all seem to shadow each other too